# Let A be a bounded infinite subset of R^2, show that A has at least a limit point.

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let A be a bounded subset of R^2 with infinite points, show that A has at least one limit point. 
How can a prove that without using compactness?

Comment: Isn't this Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem for $R^2$?

Comment: What do you mean by "have"? Do you mean there exists an $x$ which is a limit point of $A$ or there exists an $x \in A$ which is a limit point of $A$?

Comment: I mean there exists an x which is a limit point of A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

enclose $A$ in a square divided into four subsquares. at least one subsquare contains an infinite number of points. repeat the process for one such subsquare. iterate. the intersection of subsquares converges to a point, which must be a limit point of $A$.